# Add Thunderbird to Firefox as a feed subscriber application in windows

Tags: windows, firefox, thunderbird, rss

I'm trying to get Thunderbird to be my default application to subscribe to feed that I visit in firefox.

I "choose application" and put in the path of Thunderbird executable
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe`

[image]

And it doesn't work, asks me to close Thunderbird

[image]

It's strange that Firefox has Outlook as a selectable option which works flawlessly but its own brother Thunderbird isn't even on the list of defaults.

---

PS: And when I have Thunderbird closed and then do the above, it starts the Thunderbird and puts the feed in whatever folder it likes without even asking me.

Comment: re:your PS:  So the problem is only when you add the RSS feed with Thunderbird open? And if Thunderbird is closed the feed is added OK? For me, on Thunderbird side rss feeds are added automatically.

Comment: @user3169 Does it add automatically in any folder without asking? In outlook it pops up a dialog to let me decide. If that's the expected behaviour, then yes I guess the problem is only when I add them with Thunderbird already open. It tells me to close it first.

Comment: I just have one account "RSS" and everything goes there. There is no prompt. The account is set up in Account Settings. I usually add feeds with Thunderbird open. Also (obviously) make sure you are running latest versions (check under Help --About). At this point I think it may be an communication issue between Firefox and Thunderbird. I'll delete my answer since I don't think that is the issue.